# How would I open a .txt file within a jar file? Using Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar

the line of code I'm using is: InputStream is = game.class.getResourceAsStream("testing.txt"); but when I read the file it outputs null, however in the file there is the word "test", but when I run the program it still returns null, Help please :D
The code I am using is:
package Code;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class game {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream is = game.class.getResourceAsStream("/testing.txt");
    System.out.println(is);

}
```

Comment: How are you reading it? Writing it? Etc. Code is good.

Comment: Please show code and directory structure

Comment: the file is within: src/Code/testing.txt,

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake with the directory structure, the changes have been amended in the previous comment

Comment: I fixed it by putting a "/" before testing.txt, however now when i run the program I get this outputted: java.io.BufferedInputStream@4271c5bc

Comment: What are you printing? This would be a lot easier if you would show your code. It sounds like you are doing System.out.println(is); 
Try System.out.println(is.readLine());

Comment: This means you are printing an object of type `BufferedInputStream`, which simply shows the "address" of the object (because there is no sense in converting this type to some text).

Comment: package Code;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class game {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  InputStream is = game.class.getResourceAsStream("/testing.txt");
  System.out.println(is);

 }

}
~this is my code that I am using, I'm just trying to experiment with file handling atm, remember I'm a noob ;)

Comment: @WilliamSmith Please edit your question and take some time to express what you mean and format the code. Then people can easily help you and you won’t get any downvotes. :)

Comment: Ive done that now :D

Comment: Well, you asked for an input stream and you got an input stream, I can't see anything wrong there. Next step is to read the contents of the stream into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still unsure about your directory structure but this should work

```
public class game {

   public static void main(String[] args) { 
     try{
       InputStream is = game.class.getResourceAsStream("/testing.txt");
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
       System.out.println(reader.readLine());
     } catch( IOException e){
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort to help but I now get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method readLine() is undefined for the type InputStream

 at Code.game.main(game.java:9)

Comment: This is an incredibly brittle solution: it only works if the file has exactly 1 line. Any more or less and it'll either blow up or only partially read the file. (Not to mention that `InputStream` hasn't got a `readLine()` method.)

Comment: I'm not sure what @WilliamSmith is trying to do. This fixes what he was showing. I forgot there is no readLine, I fixed my solution

Comment: I tried using your solution @microsby0 but it still doesn't work!

Comment: Hm, @biziclop is correct its fairly brittle, whats the error now?

Comment: I got it to work by adding "throws IOException" but that did work but what it outputted was just 72

Comment: Ah, thats because the InputStream reads in a byte. Let me make my solution a little more elegant

Comment: If you explain more what youre trying to do I could help more. You'll likely need a loop if you want to read an entire file. This should read the first line of the file though

Comment: I literally just want to read the first line in the file

Comment: My solution should work. Please mark this solution as the answer to close this question

Comment: @WilliamSmith A word of advice: while this solution is good for demonstrating what you wanted to do, **never ever** put in an empty `catch` block in real code. It's one of the most guaranteed ways to shoot yourself in the foot.